# Invoking a method in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, methods

My code spawns a number of threads to manage communications with a number of I/O boards. Generally the threads receive events from the boards and update external data sources as necessary. The threads (1 or more) are invoked as:

```
phThreadDict[devId] = ifkit(self, phDevId, phIpAddr, phIpPort, phSerial)
phThreadDict[devId].start()
```

This works fine. However, in some cases I also need the thread to send a message to the boards. The thread contains a method that does the work and I call that method, from the main thread, as: (this example turns on a digital output)

```
phThreadDict[devId].writeDigitalOutput(digitalOut, True)
```

this is the method contained in the thread:

```
def writeDigitalOutput(self,index, state):
    interfaceKit.setOutputState(index, state)
```

`threading.enumerate()` produces:

```
{134997634: <ifkit(Thread-1, started daemon)>, 554878244: <ifkit(Thread-3, started daemon)>, 407897606: <tempsensor(Thread-4, started daemon)>}
```

and the instance is:

```
<ifkit(Thread-3, started daemon)>
```

This works fine if I have only one thread. But, if I have multiple threads, only one is used - the choice appears to be made at random when the program starts.

I suspect that storing the thread identifier in the dict is the problem, but still, it works with one thread.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing your threads in a "simple" associative array maybe you should instantiate a threadpool beforehand (you can find an example of implementation here h**p://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187-python-thread-pool/ or directly use the following lib http://pypi.python.org/pypi/threadpool).

Also instantiate a "watchdog", each of your thread will hold a reference to this watchdog, so when your threads need to do their callback they'll send back the info to this watchdog. (beware of the deadlock, look at http://dabeaz.blogspot.fr/2009/11/python-thread-deadlock-avoidance_20.html).

Note : sorry for the lame "h**p" but SO won't let me post more than 2 links....

Comment: Thanks, the first thread pool link seems to be the right direction. But, what I don't see (or am missing) is how to have the main program invoke a thread in a specific thread.  In fact, threadpool states: "[threadpool] assigns jobs to the threads by putting them in a work request queue, where they are picked up by the next available thread."  In my application, the threads are specific to a physical external I/O board, so the method must be invoked in the right thread.

Comment: Bump.  Really, no ideas on this one?